# How does the Alternate Return feature of Fortran compare to coroutines and generators?

Tags: fortran, kotlin-coroutines

How does the [Alternate Return feature of Fortran](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-alternate-return-arguments) compare to coroutines and generators?

Intel® Fortran Compiler 19.0 Developer Guide and Reference [Alternate Return Arguments](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-alternate-return-arguments):

> Alternate return (dummy) arguments can appear in a subroutine argument
>   list. They cause execution to transfer to a labeled statement rather
>   than to the statement immediately following the statement that called
>   the routine.

[Wikipedia Coroutine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) section on Generators:

Generators, also known as semicoroutines, are a subset of coroutines. Specifically, while both can yield multiple times, suspending their execution and allowing re-entry at multiple entry points, they differ in coroutines' ability to control where execution continues immediately after they yield, while generators cannot

Answer (score 2):

Alternate returns simply allow a routine to return somewhere else than immediately after the call. There is no ability for "suspending their execution and allowing re-entry". You can think of alternate returns as a computed GOTO after the call that branches to one of several labels depending on something the routine did.

Alternate returns and computed GOTO are considered "obsolescent" in the current Fortran standard and should not be used in new code.